# Orientação - Manipulação de horas e minutos Java + Postgres

Tags: java

Estou finalizando um projeto de Folha de Ponto para uma contabilidade e é meu primeiro projeto então ainda não experiência em manipular data e hora no java e no banco de dados, sem mais delongas:

Preciso única e exclusivamente fazer a seguinte conta através do sistema:

Hora Entrada                   Hora Saída Almoço              Retorno Almoço               Saída

08:00                                           11:00                                                  13:00                                    17:00

Totalizando 3horas trabalhadas pela manhã e mais 4 horas trabalhadas a tarde. Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de manipular e fazer esta conta, pensei em transformar em long mais não consegui concluir a idéias. Eu sei que de longe isso é um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável, mais gosto de entender como fazer e depois me virar.

Após assistir várias video aulas, fiz da forma abaixo, para que eu possa descobrir a duração entre  as horas de entrada e saída, mais realmente achei que ficou uma gambiarra, quem poder me ajudar a melhorar esse código, transformar 23:00 em dois atributos inteiros um de 23 e outro com valor 00 não parece estar certo para mim, desde já agradeço!

```
 public void teste(){
    int teste1 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldHora1.getText().substring(0,2)));
    int teste2 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldHora1.getText().substring(3,4)));

    int teste3 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldHora2.getText().substring(0,2)));
    int teste4 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldHora2.getText().substring(3,4)));

    LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(teste1,teste2);
    LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.of(teste3,teste4);

    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(time1, time2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo fortemente o uso da biblioteca [JodaTime](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases) para manipular datas, horas, fusos horários, etc em Java, já que as classes nativas (`Date`, `Calendar`), apesar de estarem melhores, não são práticas nem intuitivas.

Lembrando que esta biblioteca virou nativa a partir do Java-8, se está usando essa versão ou posteriores, pode utilizar diretamente as classes `LocalDateTime` e seus métodos que são muito parecidos com os do JodaTime, porém o exemplo usará JodaTime. (Valeu @Articuno).

Para extrair do banco, é só setar o retorno da consulta (`resultSet`) direto no construtor do objeto `DateTime` com o `getDate`. Ex:

```
DateTime horarioEntrada = new DateTime(resultSet.getDate("horario_entrada"));
```

Depois de obter os horários, o cálculo é bem simples. Um exemplo testável:

```
//criação dos horários
DateTime horaEntrada = new DateTime(2017,11,10, 8,00);
DateTime horaSaidaAlmoco = new DateTime(2017,11,10, 11,00);
DateTime horaRetornoAlmoco = new DateTime(2017,11,10, 13,00);
DateTime horaSaida = new DateTime(2017,11,10, 17,00);

//horas entre os horários
Integer horasManha = Hours.hoursBetween(horaEntrada, horaSaidaAlmoco).getHours();
Integer horasTarde = Hours.hoursBetween(horaRetornoAlmoco, horaSaida).getHours();

//soma das horas
Integer horasTotais = horasManha + horasTarde;
```

Nesse exemplo criei os horários na "mão" para você poder testar mas você irá pegar do banco conforme mostrado anteriormente.

---

Edit: Agora que você botou o código fica mais fácil. Ex com `LocalTime`:

```
public void teste(){
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm");
    String tempo1 = jTextFieldHora1.getText();
    String tempo2 = jTextFieldHora2.getText();

    LocalTime localTime1 = LocalTime.parse(tempo1, dtf);
    LocalTime localTime2 = LocalTime.parse(tempo2, dtf);

    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(localTime1, localTime2));
}
```

Comment: Ou simplesmente atualizar para o java-8, que já possui essas classes nativas.

Comment: Zulian fiz da forma que me mostrou e está dando erro nessa palavra Hours disse que não existe, editei minha pergunta e encontrei uma forma de fazer só não ficou legal, se poder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @DhouglasSilvaGomes, dá uma olhada!